# Solr how to write an array of data in a CSV file

Tags: csv, solr

What's the syntax to write an array for solr in a csv file?, i need to update a multivalued field but when i upload the file, the data get all in the array but like just one element like this:

```
multiField:["data1,data2,data3"]
```

instead of this

```
multiField:["data1", "data2" , "data3"]
```

how i can write this in the csv file by default?

Answer (score 1):

You can [use the `split` parameter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-CSVUpdateParameters) to split a single field into multiple values:

```
&f.multiField.split=,
```

.. should do what you want.

Comment: ok, and how i can do this using the document import from the solr web manager, in case i don't have permission to upload files to the server?